# php_ini_loaded_file not working with PHP 5.5.30, Apache 2.4 in El Capitan

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache 2.4 on my El Capitan Mac. I would like to know which php.ini is used by the server.
The output of phpinfo() tells me that that the path for the php.ini file is  the etc/ directory.
Unfortunately, there are four such files there :

```
php.ini-5.2-previous
php.ini.default
php.ini.default-5.2-previous
php.ini.default-5.2-previous~orig
```

My guess would be that it uses `php.ini.default`, but I would like to be 100% sure.
So I call  php_ini_loaded_file(), which unfortunately returns`bool(false)`. Does it mean that the PHP module in Apache does not load any php.ini at all ???

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Restart apache after making any changes in php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have any "Loaded Configuration File" row in your phpinfo() output, then probably there is **no php.ini file loaded** at all, as you suspect.

Try to copy one of the existing files to the filename *php.ini*, and restart the server. If it loads it, find out the differences between the variants and configure your system to your needs.